# Button Background Color not Changing when using props in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

This is a really, really simple thing, but I just can't get my head over this. I am a newbie in React, and am currently learning it.

I have my button here which I am trying to edit using props in react. However, the "backgroundColor" just doesn't seem to change.

Here's my code:

Button component

```
export const Button = ({ color, text }) => {
  return <button style={{ backgroundColor: { color } }}>{text}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

Main component:

```
import Button from "./Button";

const myComp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="red" text="This is a button" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default myComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct type for style prop to native elements is `Record<string, string | number>`

Your value is an object, it should be string or number

```
style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
```

Comment: Could you please expand? How should I provide a string or number?

Comment: Just like the code below, key: value, not key: { value } like your example. backgroundColor: color